# How can I make time-lapse videos of my Minecraft creations?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, recording

How can I make time-lapses of my Minecraft creations? Ideally I'd like something that can record automatically from a fixed location, either generating a bunch of images (I've got software to stitch them together) or a video. This is the kind of thing I want, I quite like this one as it doesn't show the player:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't used it yet but this looks like exactly what your after.  Seems to run a local mod so I think you maybe can even use it on servers (although you'd want to turn off the auto messages if you do).

### [Camera Studio](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/938825-145-camera-studio-v25-modloader-compatible-video-recorder/)

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a better one done on a server, I assume they had another account that just sat there and looked at the project with FRAPs running while they built it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that was done in stop motion, they would build a bit, move to a place, press F2, build some more and repeat. There are programes out there to remove the shake this effect would make. You could also do it online with one person not moving and just taking pictures this would remove the shake.

Comment: That would be fine for a small project, but I don't have nearly enough cake to persuade someone to do it for a few days.

Comment: If you install certain mods on the "camera" player you could run a script to automatically take the screenshots.

Comment: care to expand upon 'certain mods'?

Comment: @fredley I know that single player commands can do scripts but I don't if it can be installed on a server.

Answer (score 1):

One method I saw involved setting up a server on your own computer and installing the [Multishot Timelapse Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/646592-v110multishot-timelapse-modv16-camera-coming-soon/). You need to turn "online mode" to "off" on the server. Then, you login to the server (the address will be `localhost`) using your real account, then, in a separate client, login to the server in offline mode (which can be accomplished by misspelling your login name), and following the instructions for the timelapse mod. The downside of this method is, obviously, that you will need a lot of computing power to be able to run a server and 2 clients at the same time.

Comment: There's a video showing this method, but I can't seem to find it at the moment.